Apply & Show the Filter View Created
I have a drawing on the Sheet to which I have assigned the following script.
The problem is when the drawing is clicked and the script is run, the Filter View get created but is not visible in Data > Change view. Also its not shown above the sheet whee the Filter View name is shown along with the Range.

In order to make it visible in Data > Change view I have to change from the active sheet to another sheet and come back to the previous sheet and than go Data > Change view and select the Filter view manually.
How can i apply this automatically when the drawing is clicked.
function createFilterView() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const spreadsheetId = ss.getId();

  // Find the named range that starts with "tbl_"
  const namedRanges = ss.getNamedRanges();
  let namedRange;

  for (const range of namedRanges) {
    if (range.getName().startsWith("tbl_")) {
      namedRange = range.getRange();
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!namedRange) {
    Logger.log("No named range starting with 'tbl_' found.");
    return;
  }

  // Extract range details
  const startRowIndex = namedRange.getRow() - 2;
  const endRowIndex = namedRange.getLastRow();
  const startColumnIndex = namedRange.getColumn() - 1;
  const endColumnIndex = namedRange.getLastColumn();

  // Get the active user's email
  const userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  // Define the resource for the FilterView
  const resource = {
    requests: [
      {
        addFilterView: {
          filter: {
            range: {
              sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(),
              startRowIndex: startRowIndex,
              endRowIndex: endRowIndex,
              startColumnIndex: startColumnIndex,
              endColumnIndex: endColumnIndex
            },
            title: userEmail // Set the filter view title to the user's email
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  // Apply the filter view to the active sheet
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);
}


Using Google Apps Script does not allow you to refresh the Google Sheets web app toolbar options, including the list of filter views.
The closed class is Class Ui. This class doesn't have a method to refresh the Google Sheets toolbar, but it could be used to create a custom menu, dialogs and sidebars.
Something to explore is to try to get the Filter View URL and then add it to a cell, dialog or sidebar.
